# SQL Select query is taking so long time on new Server

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query, select, mysqldump

I am migrating our live website server from rackspace to AWS. We have already done all parts but stuck at below point:

One of query which is running within a second on live server, it's taking around 5 mins to execute in aws server.

I have already checked about configuration of mysql and its same. We keep same configuration as live for mysql, Tried to import database thrice but same problem persist:

Here is mysql Versions of both server:
Rackspace - 5.5.61
AWS       - 5.7.29

Here is that query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(listname), 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`id`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`reportcode`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`list_type`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`list_url`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`researchby`,  
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`linkassigndate`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`startdate`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`completeddate`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`team`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`status`,   
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`priority`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`list_url_path`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`comments`, 
               `tbcc_l_lists`.`added_by`, 
               `tbcc_l_categorygroup`.`name`,   
               `tbcc_l_listtype`.`listtype_name`, 
               (SELECT COUNT(tbcc_l_contacts.primary_list) 
                FROM tbcc_l_contacts 
                WHERE tbcc_l_lists.id=tbcc_l_contacts.primary_list )   AS `contactcount`, 
               (SELECT COUNT(tbcc_l_contacts_rejects.primary_list) 
                FROM tbcc_l_contacts_rejects 
                WHERE tbcc_l_lists.id=tbcc_l_contacts_rejects.primary_list)   AS rejectcount, 
               `tbcc_l_admins`.`username`, 
               `tbcc_l_admins`.`fname`, 
               `tbcc_l_admins`.`lname`, 
               `admins`.`username` AS `team_username`, 
               `admins`.`fname`   AS `team_fname`, 
               `admins`.`lname` AS `team_lname`, 
               `admins1`.`username` AS `addedby_username`, 
               `admins1`.`fname` AS `addedby_fname`, 
               `admins1`.`lname`   AS `addedby_lname` 
FROM `tbcc_l_lists` 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_categorygroup` ON tbcc_l_lists.categorygroup = tbcc_l_categorygroup.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_listtype`   ON tbcc_l_lists.list_type = tbcc_l_listtype.listtype_id 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_contacts` ON tbcc_l_lists.id = tbcc_l_contacts.primary_list   
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_contacts_rejects` ON tbcc_l_lists.id = tbcc_l_contacts_rejects.primary_list 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_admins`   ON tbcc_l_admins.id = tbcc_l_lists.researchby 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_admins` AS `admins` ON admins.id = tbcc_l_lists.team 
LEFT JOIN `tbcc_l_admins` AS `admins1`   ON admins1.id = tbcc_l_lists.added_by 
WHERE (1=1) LIMIT 200000;
```

I am working on this issue since last couple of days, Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: could you please add execution plans and output of show table status from both servers?

Answer (score 0):

- `DISTINCT` is not a function.  It applies to the whole row.  And it is probably unnecessary.  It takes an extra pass over the data to perform the `DISTINCT` functionality.
- `LIMIT 200000` seems quite unrealistic.  What is the goal?
- The query, without a `WHERE` clause, will scan the entire `tbcc_l_lists` table.  That takes time if the table is big.
- `COUNT(*)` is the usual pattern.  `COUNT(x)` is often misused; this means "count the row if `x is NOT NULL`.  Or did you really want that test?
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` so we can see what parts are being inefficient.
- That may lead to requesting `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.
- You say the configuration is the same -- are you referring to *both* the memory size and `my.cnf`?